# Perlin noise: I have the source code, now what?

Tags: objective-c, c, class, perlin-noise

I have been looking all over the internet on how exactly to use the Perlin noise [class](http://paulbourke.net/libraries/perlin.c) (the C version), but I can't seem to find anything.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
double height = noise1(12);
NSLog(@"%f", height);
```

I set a double equal to noise1 with a random argument. Then I output height to the console with the `NSLog` (objective-c). Now the strange thing is that the console outputs[image: console output] and [image]

---

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you just create and upload two screenshots to share two strings containing (dead-simple, while we're at it) numbers?

Comment: Yes, I did. Is there a problem?

Comment: It just seems incredibly convulted, it never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, e.g.,

```
for(double x = 0; x < 10; x+=0.1)
{
  double height = PerlinNoise1D(x,2,2,n);
  //...
}
```

Here `x` is the coordinate of the texture; it seems the functions the code is blending together are all 0 at integer values of `x` so it makes sense that their blend is also always `0`. As best as I can tell `n` is the number of functions to blend... not sure what the best value is, but 20ish seems to work well in some quick tests.